# How memory expensive is writing data to addressBook and CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-management

I am updating an adress book app.
I have a view were the user can edit the contact parameters, some of the  parameters are saved in the address book and some in core-data entity.
i have a dilemma with 2 options -

1. write the changes immediately to the
   AddressBook and core-data and save
   the changes when the user press save
   button.
2. only when the user presses the save
   button,  read the final result of
   the changes,and  then write it and
   save it to the addressBook and core
   data.

I find it hard to decide mainly because i don't know exactly what are the prices of each method?
i find it easier to me to write the changes as they immediately, and i believe that in this way the UI will be more responsive as the usage of memory is divided to  small operations.

thanks for any advice.

shani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easy to track with Instruments. It should be pretty easy for you to switch between the implementations and measure the difference

Comment: Ok I will exept that. I wantedvto understand the reason as instruments will not give me that but it seems that this the the best answer I got.